# JNA: Change String encoding for only one external native library

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, jna

We have here an JAVA application which loads and use a lots of external librarys. The default encoding of the operating system (Windows) is "windows-1252" (or "cp-1252"). But there is one external library which want all String (incoming and outgoing) in "utf-8". How can I do that? How can I change the String encoding type for only one JNA library?

Comment: All strings in Java are internally represented as UTF-16. Encoding is only relevant for input and output.

Comment: @Henry: Of course. But JNA will encodes strings which will be deliver to an external library not in UTF-16. The string will be encoded in the default encoding of the operating system (which is "Windows-1252" in my case). But I must change this encoding for only one specific external library to "utf-8" (without changing the encoding for all other Libraries). Thats my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal JNA pattern is this:

```
public interface DemoLibrary extends Library {

    DemoLibrary INSTANCE = Native.load("demoLibrary", DemoLibrary.class);

    // abstract method declarations as interface to native library
}
```

However, *Native#load* is overloaded multiple times to support customizing the bindings. The relevant overload is: [Native#load(String, Class, Map<String,?>)](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.java.dev.jna/jna/latest/com/sun/jna/Native.html#load-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-). The third argument can be used to pass options to the native library loader. The options can be found in the [com.sun.jna.Library](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.java.dev.jna/jna/latest/com/sun/jna/Library.html) Interface.

The relevant option here is `Library.OPTION_STRING_ENCODING`. That option is passed to the `NativeLibrary` instance loaded and will be used as the default encoding for this class.

The sample above becomes then

```
public interface DemoLibrary extends Library {

    DemoLibrary INSTANCE = Native.load("demoLibrary", DemoLibrary.class,
        Collections.singletonMap(Library.OPTION_STRING_ENCODING, "UTF-8"));

}
```

If you need to customize more (typemapper, calling convention), you'll need to create the option map for example in a static initializer block.

Comment: I was trying this solution with `jna-4.2.2` and `loadLibrary` as it accepts those parameters as input, and I thought it might be interchangable. It did not work. Moving to `jna-5.7.0` and `load` immediately worked.

Answer (score 1):

[Matthias Bläsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882205/1161484) is a much better solution to this specific use case. Please read it first if you only need character encoding.

My original answer is below and is more general to a wider range of applications.

An easy way to handle it is to not directly map `String` fields/args at all.  Just send and receive byte arrays from the library, and create a helper function to do the translation between Strings and the byte arrays.  As you've pointed out, you can write those bytes to an allocated `Memory` block and pass the pointer.

If you want a more permanent solution to do the same thing behind the scenes, you can use a [TypeMapper](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.5.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/TypeMapper.html) for that particular library.

The W32APITypeMapper is a good reference, with the `stringConverter` variable showing you how in unicode it maps `String` to the wide string `WString` (UTF16).

Create your own `UTF8TypeMapper` (or similar) and use Java's character set/encoding functions to translate your strings to a sequence of UTF-8 bytes.

This is untested, but should be close to what you need.  You could do a bit more abstraction to create a new `UTF8String` type that handles the details.

```
public class UTF8TypeMapper extends DefaultTypeMapper {

    public UTF8TypeMapper() {
        TypeConverter stringConverter = new TypeConverter() {
            @Override
            public Object toNative(Object value, ToNativeContext context) {
                if (value == null)
                    return null;

                String str = (String) value;
                byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                // Allocate an extra byte for null terminator
                Memory m = new Memory(bytes.length + 1);
                // write the string's bytes
                m.write(0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                // write the terminating null
                m.setByte((long) bytes.length, (byte) 0); 
                return m;
            }

            @Override
            public Object fromNative(Object value, FromNativeContext context) {
                if (value == null)
                    return null;
                Pointer p = (Pointer) value;
                // handles the null terminator
                return p.getString(0, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> nativeType() {
                return Pointer.class;
            }
        };
        addTypeConverter(String.class, stringConverter);
    }
}
```

Then, add the type mapper to the options when loading the library:

```
private static final Map<String, ?> UTF8_OPTIONS =
        Collections.singletonMap(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, new UTF8TypeMapper());

TheUTF8Lib INSTANCE = Native.load("TheUTF8Lib", TheUTF8Lib.class, UTF8_OPTIONS);
```

Comment: This is a solution as I like it! But seem's String's must be mapped to Pointer's. i took the liberty of changing this in your code section. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes you can use `Memory` objects which subclass to Pointers.  I did mention that `byte[]` might not be the best option.

Comment: The reason why byte[] not works is: If you have a function which returns an String, you will get by calling this function an exception (such as "the data type B[ is invalid" or something like that). For functions which has Strings in arguments this will work also with byte[]

Comment: You should switch to Matthias Bläsing's answer as the best... :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found is to use the Function class of JNA (see at https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Function.html ) like this:

```
public void setIp(String ip) {
    Function fSetIp = Function.getFunction("myLib", "setIp", Function.C_CONVENTION, "utf-8");

    Object[] args = {ip};

    fSetIp.invoke(args);
}
```

But I must implementing this for each function I want to call. Not sure if there is a better/easier way. If so: Please answer my question.